# Regular Expression in CS: data extraction

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0, data-extraction

I have data like this:

```
<td><a href="/New_York_City" title="New York City">New York</a></td>
```

And I would like to get *New York* out of it.

I don't have any skill in regex what so ever. I have tried this though:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("c:\\USAcityfile2.txt");
string pattern = "<td>.*</td>";
Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Regex r1 = new Regex("<a .*>.*</a>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
 string read = "";
while ((read = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    foreach (Match m in r.Matches(read))
    {
        foreach (Match m1 in r1.Matches(m.Value.ToString()))
            Console.WriteLine(m1.Value);
    }
}
sr.Close();
sr.Dispose();
```

this gave me `<a href="/New_York_City" title="New York City">New York</a>`.

How can reach to data between `<a .*>` and `</a>`? thanks.

Comment: Your input data is well-formed XML. Maybe it's better to use any XML parser?

Comment: don't know anything about XML-walking. rookie for a reason. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on a regex for this particular case, then try this:

```
String pattern = @"(?<=<a[^>]*>).*?(?=</a>)
```

`(?<=<a[^>]*>)` is a positive lookbehind assertion to ensure that there is `<a[^>]*>` before the wanted pattern.

`(?=</a>)` is a positive lookahead assertion to ensure that there is `</a>` after the pattern

`.*?` is a lazy quantifier, matching as less as possible till the first `</a>`

A good reference for regular expressions is [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

[Their lookaround explanation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: any reference that you would like to suggest? thanks it works.

Comment: @AnubhavSaini I added two links to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Only one Regex will do:

```
string pattern = "<a[^>]*>(.*)</a>";
```

Comment: tried. but it gives <a href='........</a>. I put this in first regex and commented second one.

Comment: Notice the braces, "<a[^>]*>(.*)</a>", that is called a *capture* in regex, you can grab that capture in C#, it should be something like: if(match.find()){string s = match.group(1); }, Sorry, I don't know much about C#...

Answer (score 0):

```
           foreach (Match m1 in r1.Matches(m.Value.ToString()))
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(m1.Value);
                    string[] res = m1.Value.Split(new char[] {'>','<'});
                    Console.WriteLine(res[2]);
                }
```

Did the trick, for this particular example. Still not what I am looking.

Answer (score 0):

```
var g = Regex.Match(s, @"\<a[^>]+\>([^<]*)").Groups[1];
```

To find all values of `<a>` in your file you may use the following (easier) code:

```
        var allValuesOfAnchorTag =
            from line in File.ReadLines(filename)
            from match in Regex.Matches(line, @"\<a[^>]+\>([^<]*)").OfType<Match>()
            let @group = match.Groups[1]
            where @group.Success
            select @group.Value;
```

However you seem to work with XML as @kirill-polishchuk correctly pointed out. If that is true code is even more simple:

```
        var values = from e in XElement.Load(filename).Descendants("a")
                         select e.Value;
```

Comment: I guess, you have changed code to easier one. xml-code throws error: There are multiple root elements. tried: `.Descendants("tr").Descendants("td").Descendants("a")`

Comment: @AnubhavSaini, Looks like your input document isn't XML.

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk html actually.

Answer (score 0):

As per OP comment, that input document is HTML, it'd be better to use HTML parser, e.g.: [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). You can use XPath `//td/a` to obtain desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Using the HTML Agility Pack ([project page](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), [nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack)), this does the trick:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("your html here"); 
// or doc.Load(stream);

var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.DescendantNodes("a");
// or var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td/a") ?? new HtmlNodeCollection();

foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    string city = node.InnerText;
}

// or var linkTexts = nodes.Select(node => node.InnerText);
```